# Pipe In Kid’s Closet: Asbestos?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, asbestos

There’s what I believe is a ventilation plumbing-related pipe in my daughter’s closet.  I’m pretty sure it’s cast iron and not lead, because a magnet sticks to it.  I’m concerned about environmental hazards in my old home - especially asbestos.  There’s no discernible wrap on the pipe.  Don’t know if there’s potential asbestos containing material where the joints meet?  Slightly worried that it’s not a good idea to have her clothing etc touching the pipe.   Is there any reason for my concern, or am I just being paranoid?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge, there’s no asbestos in pipe joint compound (aka pipe dope). You could scratch some off and send it to a lab if you really wanted to put your mind to rest. You might also swab that paint with a home lead test kit — that’s an actual possibility.

Comment: It looks more like just paint.  Asbestos is usually more thicker like a thin blanket covering.  It is used for insulation(fire/heat).  I doubt you could see the threads/letters if covered with asbestos.

Answer (score 3):

Asbestos is not dangerous when you touch it. It is dangerous if you breathe loose fibers. So even if there is asbestos here, it is covered up, painted over, etc. As long as you don't remove the paint, etc there is no concern.

Answer (score 1):

Only asbestos in friable form is dangerous.  Lead in the paint is more likely, though not very.  Both unlikely concerns could be addressed by a careful wrap with foil tape which could allay remaining fears/uncertainty.  Might be worth it if only to overcome sometimes difficult concerns regarding child safety.

Comment: No lead in the paint luckily